# Selecting highest value without using max?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns. CustNo and CustBal

Trying to write script to select CustNo with the highest balance. I tried using max and I can get that to work if I just use CustBal column but not in this case. I think it could be a WHERE item with something after CUSTBAL?

```
SELECT CUSTNO, CUSTBAL
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTBAL
```

Comment: I'm getting closer. Now I have highest balance but doesnt include CustNo

SELECT CUSTNO, CUSTBAL FROM CUSTOMER;
SELECT MAX (CustBal) FROM CUSTOMER

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Comment: Terminology: You are trying to write a query. Not everything you write is a "script."

Comment: @Prdp - I agree with that request in general. But for THIS problem? Not really needed IMO.

Comment: @mathguy - Seriously question is not clear. I had too many guesses

Comment: @Prdp - How can it be any clearer than "select CustNo with the highest balance"? No guessing needed, what is there to guess?

Comment: @mathguy - Then why `Max` aggregate is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why without using MAX?

You need to compute the MAX separately, because you can only do that at the end of a query (using the aggregate function MAX in the SELECT clause), and you can't mix individual rows and aggregates in one query. So you must compute the MAX in a subquery.

```
select custno, custbal
from   customer
where  custbal = (select max(custbal) from customer)
;
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it! I was misusing max from the beginning.

Comment: To tell the truth, you can mix individual rows and ANALYTIC functions in the same query, but in this case you would still need an "outer" query to select just the row you need. And at the point you're at in your studies, analytic functions are still several months away (probably). Just file that away for future reference!

Answer (score 3):

alternatively:

```
select * from
(select custno, custbal from customer order by custbal desc)
where rownum = 1
```

..if you have 12c:

```
select custno, custbal from customer
order by custbal desc
fetch next 1 rows only
```

however these will only return a single row even if there are multiple customers with the same highest balance. if you want all records with the highest custbal, then:

```
select custno, custbal from
(select *, dense_rank() over (order by custbal desc) as rank from customer)
where rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nicky,
You can also use simple group by function,

```
SELECT CUSTNO, MAX(CUSTBAL)
    FROM CUSTOMER
      GROUP BY CUSTNO 
      ORDER BY CUSTNO
```

GROUP BY - Provides you the maximum of CUSTBAL with respect to CUSTNO
ORDER BY - Displays the result in ascending order of CUSTNO column